# Showing that a series converges.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A_2$ be the set of all real sequences $\{x_j\}_{j\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that
$\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} x_j^2<\infty$.

I'm to show that if $\textbf{x}=\{x_j\}$ and $\textbf{y}=\{y_j\}\in A_2$, then
$\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} x_jy_j$ converges.

Now I think I can use the Cauchy-Shwarz inequality: $|\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} x_jy_j|^2\leq \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}|x_j|^2\cdot \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} 
|y_j|^2<\infty
$.

By taking the square root on each side I obtain
$|\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} x_jy_j|\leq \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}|x_j|\cdot \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} 
|y_j| < \infty
$.

Is this enough, or do I have to do something about the absolute value signs, and if so what?

Answer (score 2):

Yes CS inequality is a good way since

$$0\le\left|\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} x_jy_j\right| \leq \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}x_j^2\cdot \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} y_j^2$$

as $n\to \infty$

$$0\le\left|\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} x_jy_j\right| \leq \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}x_j^2\cdot \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} y_j^2<\infty$$

thus the given series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: why did you unaccep? some doubt or something not clear?

Answer (score 1):

Let $n \in \mathbb N$ and $s_n:=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} |x_jy_j|$. By Cauchy - Schwarz we have

$0 \le s_n \le (\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}|x_j|^2)^{1/2}\cdot(\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}|y_j|^2)^{1/2} \le (\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}|x_j|^2)^{1/2}\cdot(\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}|y_j|^2)^{1/2} =:C$  for all $n$.

Hence, the sequence $(s_n)$ is bounded and increasing. Conclusion: $(s_n)$ is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality holds the way you wrote it down. You don't have to take the square roots though (and in fact you shouldn't because your second line isn't true). You can already conclude that the series converges if its square converges.